# Print Statement in SQL procedure should affect Performance?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server procedures and I have a habit of using of `Print` statements in the stored procedures to differentiate the code of procedure.

I have almost 200-250 procedures in my DB.
Should print statement affect the performance?
I am working on multi-user Windows application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found when running the below on my desktop that commenting out the print knocked about 15 seconds off the execution time meaning the average impact was 15µs in my simple test. `RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT` added an average of just over double that.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME2

DECLARE 
  @count INT

SET @count = 1

SET @date = SYSUTCDATETIME()

WHILE @count < 1000000
BEGIN
--RAISERROR ('%d',0,1, @count) WITH NOWAIT
--PRINT @count
  SET @count = @count + 1
END

SELECT DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND, @date, SYSUTCDATETIME()) / 1000000.
```

Comment: just tried that query, i had a total of 17 seconds with the "print @count", and 2,2 seconds with the print commented

Answer (score 5):

A handful of `PRINT` statements will have a negligible effect on performance - `PRINT`s in loops that are executed many thousands of times, however, may well cause performance issues.

It's unlikely that if you're experiencing performance problems with your queries that `PRINT` is the culprit - however, if in doubt, try some experiments!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there is an *additional* overhead introduced to the *overall* performance of your given process because you are asking SQL Server to *pass output to the client*, which you would not be doing otherwise (i.e. without the use of the PRINT statement).

Quantifying an additional overhead, in terms of will it have an impact on overall performance, will depend on just how much of an additional overhead you are applying.

So in other words, go and test it out.