# Is there any disadvantage to using PRINT in my stored procs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I can't believe after all these years I am asking this question, but...

Is there any disadvantage to using PRINT in my stored procs?  I've bee using it for debugging, but should I remove them after I am done?  I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print is function call that i use only for debugging stored procedure ....it affect the performance  but its ver very minimal cost as its function call..if possbile remove it or comment it in you code..

**Note** : PRINTs in loops that are executed many thousands of times, however, may well cause performance issues.

Also check alreay ask question : [Print Statement in SQL procedure should affect Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690127/print-statement-in-sql-procedure-should-affect-performance)

Answer (score 1):

If the print statements will also being execute in a released version (as opposed to debug version), it might result in a (very big) performance hit.

Normally print statements are quite costly to perform, but I don't know much about stored procedures.

**Edit**: as others already confirmed, `PRINT` is only used as/in debug versions, so no real penalty except for the call.

Answer (score 0):

It really won't make a difference, you can leave them if you want.