# SQL Print statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a disadvantage of having PRINT statements in stored procs?. The benefit is that I can easily copy/paste in query window and debug. However, in production environment is there any side effect of having them there?
Thanks

Comment: Performance, I/O, do what is necessary to complete a transaction no more, no less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where you're using the PRINT statements.

If a PRINT statement occurs in a **loop** that are run thousands of time, the performance will be impacted. But if you don't use it in a loop, and it's only a couple of PRINT statements, i can't see a huge performance issue.

However my personal preference is to leave all PRINT statements out of production code if they're only used for debugging purposes.

Also this was asked before: [Print Statement in SQL procedure should affect Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690127/print-statement-in-sql-procedure-should-affect-performance) and as you can see it can have a big influence in the perfomance.